# Where versus were

Tags: past-tense

New York Times editorial today says:

> The Bronx district attorney should be applauded for refusing to prosecute bad arrests that officers were unable to prove *were* warranted.

Should it be:

> The Bronx district attorney should be applauded for refusing to prosecute bad arrests that officers were unable to prove *where* warranted.

Comment: 'Where' is a place - think of 'here' with a 'w' on the end.

Comment: 'where warranted' (or 'where X') is a phrase that can work in some circumstances, and almost works (but not really), but 'were' is correct here. It is very much a coincidence that the single letter change allows such a change in parsing (but coincidences happen all the time). To undo the ellipsis: "The officers were unable to prove that the _bad arrests were_ warranted".

Answer (score 1):

No. *Were* is the correct word, because there was no evidence the arrests *were* warranted.